# use different parameter for a success callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on someone else's code. I have this simple AJAX call in jQuery:

```
function getWSData (which, data, idVR)
{
   if(which == 'verCandAll')
   {
      funcSuccess = verCandSuccess;
      data = {'name' : 'val'};
   }
   else 
   {
      funcSuccess = verElseSuccess;
      data = {'name2' : 'val2'};
   }

   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: wsURL,
      data: data,
      success: funcSuccess,
      error:function ()
      {
           $("#msg").ajaxError(function()
           {
               popWaiting(false);
               alert(verGenericCallError);
           });
      },
      dataType: 'xml'
   });
}

function verCandSuccess(xml){ ... }

function verElseSuccess(xml){ ... }
```

It's really simple. The only problem I have is the `success` callback. In case of `verElseSuccess` I would send a second parameter to that function, more precisely i would handle the `idVR` (an input parameter of `getWSData`). How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, you can do:

```
...
if(which == 'verCandAll') {
    ...
}
else {
    // create an anonymous function that calls verElseSuccess with a second argument
    funcSuccess = function(xml) {
       verElseSuccess(xml, idVR);
    };
    data = {'name2' : 'val2'};
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Underscore.js [partial](http://underscorejs.org/#partial) function:

```
funcSuccess = _.partial(verElseSuccess, idVR);
```